# Can I have multiple sessions at the same in PHP?

Tags: php, session

I have a project and I would like to know if it's possible to have two sessions at the same time.

E.g.

I have a user which is a football player (he has a log in) and I want him to log in on a team to know the updates.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
session_id("player");

session_start();

session_id("team");

session_id("player");
```

This gives me an error that sais that a session had already been started.

Comment: "*If id is specified, it will replace the current session id. `session_id()` needs to be called before `session_start()` for that purpose.*" http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if it's possible to have two sessions at the same time.

Well... no. You can't have multiple *simultaneous* sessions. But you can start one, then close it with `session_write_close` and start another session... *if it's really required.*

```
session_id("player"); // are you sure that you don't want use `session_name` here?
session_start();

// ... work with session id "player"

session_write_close();

session_id("team");
session_start();

// ... work with session id "team"
```

Also, you may want use `session_name` instead of `session_id`. One sets the current session name, the other the SID.

Comment: Ok, I will have to make it work out that way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `if it's really required.` is the most important line in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bit late for the answer but I had the same issue and I solved it with two dimensional arrays.
In your case it would be something like this:

Login into system:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = 10
$_SESSION['username'] = 'XYZ';
```

Now if the user clicks on a team, which has the id 20 than the session could look like this:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = 10
$_SESSION['username'] = 'XYZ';
$_SESSION['team'][20]['teamname'] = 'ABC';
$_SESSION['team'][20]['SOME_TEAM_SPECIFIC_PROPERTY'] = 'SOME_TEAM_SPECIFIC_VALUE';
...
```

This would make it possible being logged into more then one team at the same time for instance if you have opened more than one tab etc...

Cheers